# Develop in Camel and run in Camel k

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, apache-camel-k

I want to build a integration route in camel-k. But for better debugging (f.e. adding break-points) i have build the integration-route with camel in a maven project. This project now contains multiple classes as dependencies (logic and separate processors) in multiple files. The route works fine, now i want to deploy it in kubernetes with camel-k. Is there a convenient way for packing all needed classes when building the route with kamel cli? This way both uses (camel and camel k.) would be possible within the same project. In other discussions one solution that have been pointed out was to pack the classes as jar's and add them as maven dependencies in modline, but with that approach every time a change would be made everything had to be repacked. I also tried to load all classes with the kamel run command, but the integration could not connect the classes that way.

Comment: With the latest camel-k, the correct approach is to pack everything in a jar or use jitpack. For example you may have a github repository and use jitpack to always have a ready jar each time you commit something new.

Comment: yes i went with this approach. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69844968/6528166 which removes Maven as requirement. You can provide the jar directly.